# Making a GUI shader in GLSL c++/opengl/freeglut

Tags: opengl, glsl

How do you make a shader that will draw ontop of everything else? Im using an approach where I draw square faces in 3d space to simulate a 2d box, but when I make a 3d object, it will clip over the 2d boxes as I move around.

How do you go about making 2d boxes that are drawn directly onto screen, but without clipping thru stuff in 3d space.

Im using openGL and glsl, swapping between shaders as I call objects draw call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you simply call `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` before drawing your GUI and after drawing your scene/screen.

That way, you draw your GUI on top of the scene and is unaffected by depth test.

For the shader, i think a basic shader will do.

---

I hope i remember it correctly.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Took 1 second, altho I feel maybe I shouldve figured this out myself thanks anyway :D

Comment: no problemo ;D i'm studying opengl myself

Comment: I love it compared to direct3d. Do you know freeglut as well? Or do you use the glfw approach?

Comment: I've never tried direct3d before so i can't say anything. For c++ i use sfml and glfw for java.

Comment: oh yeah, I use sfml for sound and networking, altho I really should look at those from more of a standards perspective. Especially networking. cool =) I didnt like glfw, for c++ anyway.

Comment: glfw is a little rough in the eyes, at least for me.. but oh well.l